# Not able to access the output of Pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and pandas, but I cannot find the answer to my problem anywhere.

When I try to access/print the output of a pd.groupby operation, I only seem to get the following output:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at....>
```

For example, I create DataFrame a, and then try to groupby col2:

```
In: a=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4,5],"col2":["a","b","a","a","b"]})

Out:a 
col1 col2
1     a
2     b
3     b
4     a
5     a

5 rows × 2 columns 

In: b=a.groupby("col2")
Out: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at...>
```

and if I print b

```
 In: print b
 Out:<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at ...>
```

However, I would have expected print b=a.groupby("col2") to give:

```
In: b=a.groupby("col2")
Out:  col1 col2
        1     a
        3     a
        4     a
        2     b
        5     b
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to view the contents of a groupby, you need to call one of the methods you want to view it by. The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) contains more examples. For example:

```
>>> b.count()
      col1  col2
col2
a        3     3
b        2     2

>>> b.mean()
      col1
col2
a     2.666667
b     3.500000
```

However, you can get the output you were expecting without using groupby by calling `sort` on your original data frame:

```
>>> c = a.sort(columns=('col2', 'col1'))
>>> print c
   col1 col2
0     1    a
2     3    a
3     4    a
1     2    b
4     5    b
```

Doing `a.sort(columns=('col2', 'col1'))` will sort your dataframe based on col2 first, then col1 second.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, you need to call a method to view the grouped object. To quickly view your grouped object you can also use .first() method to see the first grouped items.  So it would be b.first.  Documentation is in: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).